# Hibernate cascading merge with non-persistent objects

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-cascade

I have the following structure in my project:

```
public class A {
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.PERSIST,
        org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.REFRESH, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.MERGE})
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id")
    private List<B> bs;
}

public class B {
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "b_id")
    private C c;
}

public class C {
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = TjenesteFraIN.class,
        cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinTable(name = "c_d",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "c_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "d_id"))
    private List<D> ds;
}

public class D {
    ...
}
```

Then, a scenerio where I have a detached A-object, with a reference to a detached B-object, which in turn has a reference to a detached C-object, which has references to a couple of D-objects. (I'm using JMS, so they are really really detached). Like this:

```
final A a = getA(123); //load A-object from database
final C c = a.getSpecialC();

c.addD(getD(1)); //get Ds from database
c.addD(getD(2));

//Serialize A and send JMS-call to store the A

//On the other side, deserialize A, and then call

public A mergeA(final A a) {
    return getSession(false).merge(a);
}
```

Now, the detached A will be merged with the database representation of the A, the same for B and C, but what will happen with the new referenced from the C to the Ds? I'm seeing in practice that it does not work, nothing is stored in the c_d connection table, but i don't understand why. Is it due to limitations in Hibernate/JPA, or am I missing something with regards to my configuration?

Update:

By using the debugger, I was able to an explicit getSession().merge() on the C-object, and then it's references to D got stored in the database. Still don't quite get why Hibernate cascade won't take care of this for me, but will keep digging.

Comment: Class B has a list of Cs, so the annotation is wrong (@ManyToOne). Maybe you should start with a part of the implementation, and if that works, extend it.   You should also give the error/stacktrace.

Comment: Typo on my behalf, its really a single object thats being referenced. There is no errors or stacktraces, it just doesn't persist.

Comment: Maybe you can try to use only the JPA annotations, not the Hibernate annotations.  You can also try first to make a simpler case to work.  Merging C with Ds.  If that works, Merging B with Cs with Ds, ...